# Best way to export multiples user control to pdf with ASP.NET and jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

Actually i'm working in ASP.NET Application, 
I'm using multiple User Control (.ascx) that the user can see when click a bootstrap tab.

So, i want to add a button to download in PDF file, all the user controls that i have in the web application, with the information that the application load when click in each user control.

For example, i have 3 tabs and when i click some tab it loads some User Control with the data that i show i it. 
So i want to append this 3 user controls in the same pdf file when the user press some button, what can i use to do that?.

Comment: Try rewording your question, it's hard to understand. Do you want to user controls in your pdf?

Comment: As well go to paint and give us a conceptual picture of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Would jQueryUI solve this problem?  They support tabs and you can create different features on each tab (ex. 3 different tabs  with three different UI/Buttons).

[jqueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)